# Can't launch Python IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, python-3.5

I already have **Python** and **numpy** installed. However, since I need to install **scipy** as well, I had to install **numpy+mkl**. After installing following [these steps](https://youtu.be/SrRh1V1Z748), I can not seem to launch **Python IDLE** any longer.

Comment: Please provide more information. What version of each of the things you've listed are you using. What do you mean you can't launch IDLE? What is happening, what isn't? Are you getting an error message? Do you have the same results as the video? If not, at what point does it deviate and how so?

Comment: The "Python IDLE", it's like the editor of Python Shell. Before I can launch the editor (Python IDLE). After following the steps, and replacing the existing "numpy" folder, I can no longer launch/open the editor. It's Python 3.5